# Make function wait for result in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I'm building a component with Vue (version 2.x) based on google maps API.

In this API there is an embedded function that gets the borders of the map: getBounds() ([ref](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)).

In my code, I initialize the map with the border object equals to 0:

```
          currentBorders: {
              b: {
                  b: 0,
                  f: 0,
              },
              f: {
                  b: 0,
                  f: 0,
              },
          },
```

After that, I display the map with a certain centre and I execute the getBounds() function to get the current value of the map after it has been centred:

```
      getBorders() {
          console.log(this.currentBorders); // -> prints the object with all values equal to 0

          this.currentBorders = this.$map.getBounds();

          console.log(this.currentBorders); // -> prints undefined

          return {
              llc_lat: this.currentBorders.f.b,
              llc_lng: this.currentBorders.b.b,
              urc_lat: this.currentBorders.f.f,
              urc_lng: this.currentBorders.b.f,
          };
      },
```

Now, the problem is that during the first execution I have currentBorders set to 0, but the first execution of getBounds() returns undefined, probably because the map is not loaded yet.

What I would like to do is to block the execution of that code until getBounds return something meaningful. Is that the way to go? How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
This is how I initialize the map, through deferredReady:

```
  deferredReady() {
      this.$map.setOptions({
          styles: mapStyles(),
      });

      this.initializeMapOverlay();
      this.canvasContext = this.mapCanvas.getContext("2d");
      this.$map.addListener("idle", this.idleHandler);
      this.$map.addListener("zoom_changed", () => {
          this.resizeCanvas();
          this.clearCanvas();
      });
      this.$map.addListener("mousemove", this.mouseoverHandler);
      this.$map.addListener("drag", this.fetchHexagons());
  },
```

Comment: Can you show us the code about your map instantiation and you `getBounrds()` call ?

Comment: Why not just wait to call `getBounds` until after the map initializes? Or is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably wait to execute your code until you know that the map is fully loaded.  We can do so like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    // idle state is triggered once map is fully loaded, or failed to load. 
});
```

This way you can guarantee that your code will run only when the map is fully loaded and all of the respective objects are accessible.  Just put your code in the body of the event listener.

See if that does the trick for you.

**Edit**

I see that you do have the idle event defined in your code.  I am not sure how vue works, but perhaps there is a way to run your code once that event is ran.  Perhaps put the code within your `idleHandler` function and see if it works there.